# Every finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ has a unique Hausdorff topology?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

When I was reading my notes, I encountered a problem that I don't know how to start with.

> Prove that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$ there is a unique topology on $V$ making it a Hausdorff topological vector space.

My guess is that we can construct a topology on $V$ and show that it is Hausdorff and unique but what kind of topology should I start with? I was thinking to start with a topology that every points are closed s.t. it is Hausdorff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an isomorphism $T: V \to F^{n}$ for some $n$ and we can  declare $U$ to be open in $V$ if $T(U)$ is open in $F^{n}$. This makes $V$ a Hausdorff TVS.

It is a well known fact that all linear maps on finite dimensional TVS's are continuous.  Hence, if $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are two Hausdorff vector topologies on $V$ then the identity map $: (V,\tau_1) \to (V,\tau_2)$ is a homeomorphism which proves that $\tau_1=\tau_2$.

Comment: +1, nice answer. So the topology of the field fixes the topology of its finite-dimensional TVS. (By the way, there is a minor typo, $(V,\tau_2)$).

Comment: For Hausdorffness, are we using the fact that $\mathbb{F}^n$ is Hausdorff and the isomorphism between $V$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @Edi

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Am I correct to say that if two tvs are isomorphic, then they are homeomorphic as a top. space? Since we can consider the isomorphism $f$ as linear operator such that it is continuous and we can also define another linear inverse of $f$ which is cts as well, and that means they are homeomorphic?

Comment: Yes, you are right again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! @KaviRamaMurthy